How do I highlight a Wordpress Menu Item for a page that is not on the Menu?
I am writing a Wordpress site using the block editor (Spectra One theme).
I have a menu item called News. When I click on it the News page appears and the News menu item is highlighted.
The News page has links to other news pages on it, e.g. a link to a page containing News Item 1, a link to a page containing News Item 2 etc. As soon as I click on one of these links however, the News menu item loses its highlighting.
How do I retain the highlighting of the News menu item?
Is it possible to do this via css?
(I know I can retain the highlighting of the News menu item if I add News Item 1, News Item 2 etc. to a submenu, but I don't want to do this.)
I thought the answer might lie in assigning the News page as the parent page of News Item 1, News Item 2 etc. and using current-page-ancestor but have got nowhere with this. Probably I am misunderstanding something basic. A potential solution I have found on the web involves adding code to the footer.php file but as it is a block theme it doesn't have a footer.php file.
I would be eternally grateful for any help.

It can be done via CSS if the HTML output gives you something to track back to... ....failing that, you may need to re-write the nav walker.
